# Save resources to a folder path (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, loops, resources

I'm creating a setup executable in visual basic.net. All of the files, that are going to be extracted, are stored in my project resources. The path, to where the files are supposed to be extracted, is stored in a variable called "varInstallDir". Now, I'm stuck finding the path of my own project resources.

My plan is: Loop through every file in my project resources and copy it into the path stored in varInstallDir. On that note: Does anyone got a better or easier idea to this?

Could anyone explain me the path of my.resources?

Thanks in advance, 
Max

Comment: Depends on how you've added the resources to a degree, what's the build action for these resources?

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this in COMPLETELY the wrong way. The whole point of resources is that they are NOT separate files. They are data compiled into your EXE file. There are no files for you to loop through.

When you add a file to your app on the *Resources* page of the project properties, that file will be copied under a dedicated *Resources* folder in your project. That folder is part of your PROJECT, not part of your APPLICATION. When you build, those files are read and the data they contain is embeded into your EXE file. In your code, you're supposed to access that data via a property of `My.Resources`. The type of that property depends on the type of the file, e.g. if you add a file named *SomeImage.jpg* then the property will be `My.Resources.SomeImage` and it will be of type `Bitmap`.

So, in short, stop trying to do what you're trying to do because there is nothing to do. Resource files exist in your project only and are part of your EXE once compiled.